# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\cos (1/n^2)$ Converges or Diverges using divergence test.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\cos (1/n^2)$

For this sum, if I use the divergence test, am I allowed to say that:

$\lim_{x \to \infty} (-1)^n\cos (1/n^2)$
= $\lim_{x \to \infty} (-1)^n*\lim_{x \to \infty}\cos (1/n^2)$

Which diverges because first limit doesn't exist and the second one is equal to 1?

This means $\lim_{x \to \infty} (-1)^n\cos (1/n^2) \neq 0$

So it diverges.

If I can't do that, what convergence test should I should?

Comment: Be careful: just because you *make* something have a part that is divergent does not actually make the *entire* expression divergent.  Consider $a_n = 1$ for all $n$ (yes, a *constant* sequence).  Since $a_n = (-1)^n(-1)^n$, if I said $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n \lim_{n \to \infty}  (-1)^n$ and each limit on the right does not exist, would you think $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative approach:

As $~\displaystyle n \to \infty, ~~\cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \to 1$.

Therefore, the terms of the series approach

$+1, -1, +1, - 1, \cdots$.

If needed, $\epsilon, \delta$ can be called off the bench to complete the analysis, under the hypothetical conclusion that there exists some limit $L$ such that the series converges to $L$.

**Edit**
See also the comment that I left, just after the answer of Lee Mosher.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the sequence of terms $(-1)^n \cos(1/n^2)$ does not converge to zero, and you may use that fact to conclude that the series diverges.

However, your proof that it does not converge to zero is faulty. The hypothesis of the theorem
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n y_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n
$$
is that both limits on the right hand side *exist*, but $(-1)^n$ has no limit. So you'll need to do something else there...

Comment: So I can simply say instead that as n becomes large, the cos part gets closer to 1, therefore the terms of the series are going to get closer to + 1 -1+1-1...  , so it never converges?

Comment: @R3wind Actually, a careful reading of [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) indicates that for divergence, it is sufficient to show that $|a_n|$ does not go to $0$, as $n \to \infty$.  The last part of my answer was provided just in case it is *premature* to burden you with the Alternating Series test.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to phrase your exact idea which is much more clear and I think no one will argue with is the following:

Suppose the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n\cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

does exist. Then we have that the following exists:

$$\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n.$$

But we know already that the limit on the right hand side does not exists, so we have a contradiction, and the limit does not exist.